# Build iOS App from XML file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch

I develop apps for some congresses with a program and speakers etc. There are cases when I have to change the program very quickly. There's not enough time to send it to Apple to let them review the app.

My question is if it is possible to store XML files on a server which will be downloaded when they changed. If it is, is it also possible to store data how the cells should look like? The background image should also be dynamically.

Does Apple reject this type of application or is it O.K.?

**EDIT**
So using plist files is more efficient?
Another thing: When I do something like the following

- Change the content of each table view cell
- Change the appearance of the table view and its cells
- Change the user interaction options, e.g. to control which cells the user can tap on
- Enable / Disable functions like notifications via the internet

Is it right, that Apple won't reject apps that do something like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to put XML files on a server and affect the different properties of all views (frame, background colour, alpha, even images if you also download them).

I suggest using NSDictionary instead of an XML, because downloading the file and parsing it is made very easily in a single function: `initWithContentsOfURL:`. It is also possible to edit the plist files for the NSDictionary using XCode.

Just remember a few things:

1. You do not want to block the UI during the download, so ou probably want to download in a different thread, or at least ha an animated indicator that the file is being downloaded.
2. Make sure that you application responds correctly if the file cannot be downloaded (the user does not have Wifi access and no data plan, the user is using airplane mode, etc.
3. Some mechanism like eTag would help you diminish the load on the server and speed-up the loading by not redownloading the file if it has not changed.

Many application seem to use this technique to provide different skins and they are accepted by Apple, as long as what you download only affects UI.

Answer (score 3):

It is not only allowed, it is recommended. see [WWDC 2010: Session 117 - Building a Server-driven User Experience](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) for tons of tricks and implementation details.

Also [WWDC 2011: Session 114 - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) has some updates, how to streamline the change of appearance.